# url.action call with parmeter in javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I want to load an image from the database when on page load and when clicking a button.

when form is loading it is working fine, but when i click the button,
i need to pass the value from the dropdown and call the controller on javascript using Url.Action.

when i click the button, getting
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 ()

controller method:

```
public FileContentResult MyAction(int compId)
        {
            byte[] img = new byte[100000];
           
                img = _unitOfWork.Company.GetAll().Where(a => a.Id == compId).
                    Select(a => a.PhotoAd).FirstOrDefault();
            if (img == null)
            {
                return null;
            }
            return new FileContentResult(img, "img/jpg");
        }
```

View:

```
<body>
    &nbsp;
   <div class="col-4" >
       <div class="form-group row">
            <div class="col-2">
                <label asp-for="forCompList.CompId">Company</label>
             </div>
             <div class="col-8">
                   @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.forCompList.CompId, Model.CompList,
                                                new { @class = "form-control" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-2 text-right">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" style="background-color:forestgreen" onclick="LoadImage()">
                <i class="fa fa-refresh"></i> &nbsp; Load Company Image</button>
        </div>
        <div>
        <img src= '@Url.Action("MyAction", "AdImage", new{path="img/jpg", compId = ViewBag.compId})' id="AdImage"/>
        </div>
    </div>
    &nbsp;
   
</body>
@section Scripts{
    <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function LoadImage() 
        {
            var cid = document.getElementById('forCompList_CompId').value;
            window.alert(cid);
            $('#AdImage').src = 
            '@Url.Action("MyAction", "AdImage",new{path="img/jpg"})?compId='+cid;
            
        }
    </script>
```

the error on the browser:
[image]

Comment: Have you debugged to see what the 500 error is?  most likely it's because your compId is not being passed through to the url.action as you append it after - if you want to use a querystring like that then you would need to use the route for that action instead of creating the route on the fly

Comment: Hi Pete, i updated the post with a screenshot of the error on the broswer, the url looks correct

Comment: The url vom the source window and from the console error don't fit toghether. In the source window you have two question marks whereas the error shows a question mark and an ampersand. Furthermore the ids are different. Additionally, you are passing two parameters the the request, but your handler only does have one parameter. HAve you tried setting a breakpoint to your handler on the serverside? Is it even called? Is an exception thrown?

Comment: yes, there is a breakpoint on the server side, when page is loading it is getting the image and loads it fine, when called from JS breakpoint is not invoked

Comment: will you include your routing and the controller name in your question?

Comment: Hi @Kobi, did you set breakpoint and check if this line `img = _unitOfWork.Company.` makes any error? BTW, I cannot get into the action when use `$('#AdImage').src`.

Answer (score 0):

i would change ajax to this

```
$('#AdImage').attr('src','@Url.Action("MyAction", "AdImage")' + '?path=img/jpg&compId=' + cid);
```